# Adding Attachment, Cc & Bcc in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am newbie and I don't know how to add attachment, Cc & Bcc in a vb project. I've added a Button(Button1) labeled 'Send', Its code is given below:

```
        Dim message As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtptxtbx.Text, Port.Value)

        Try
            message = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(Emailtxtbx.Text, totxtbx.Text, subtxtbx.Text, RichTextBox1.Text)

            If ssl.Checked = True Then
                smtp.EnableSsl = True
            Else
                smtp.EnableSsl = False
            End If


            If authentication.Checked = True Then
                smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(usernametxtbx.Text, passwordtxtbx.Text)
            Else
                smtp.Credentials = Nothing
            End If

            If attachment.Checked = True Then
                'I want to add the attachment code here
            End If
            If Cc.Checked = True Then
                'I want to add the Cc code here
            End If
            If Bcc.Checked = True Then
                'I want to add the Bcc code here
            End If


            Try

                smtp.Send(message)
                MessageBox.Show("Message Sent Successfully", " OneClick Email Sender", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                ProgressBar1.Value = 100
            Catch exc As Net.Mail.SmtpException
                MessageBox.Show("Please check your internet connection. And make sure that you fill everything correct.", " OneClick Email Sender", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
       Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Please fill the details for sending the Email.")
       End Try
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vbnet.aspx?cat=7

Comment: `CC` and `Bcc` are both properties of your `MailMessage` object, not the SMTP client itself.

Comment: helrich, Thanks.... I got the CC and Bcc but I still need the attachment thing.

Comment: I got the attachment too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer... :-p
code for attachment:

```
message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(attachmenttxtbx.Text))
```

Code for cc and bcc:

```
message.CC.Add(cctxtbx.Text)
message.Bcc.Add(bcctxtbx.Text)
```

Thanks helrich and sparkyword!!!